# `AttributeError: rint` when using numpy.round

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
[[41.743617 -87.626839]
 [41.936943 -87.669838]
 [41.962665 -87.65571899999999]]
```

I want to round the numbers in the array to two decimal places, or three. I tried using numpy.around and numpy.round, but both of them give me the following error:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3084618_20130514-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2452, in round_
    return round(decimals, out)
AttributeError: rint
```

i used `numpy.around(x, decimals = 2)`
and `numpy.round(x,decimals=2)`

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to do this efficiently for a large array?

Comment: write a function that multiplies by 100 (or 1000), rounds, then divides by 100 (or 1000)

Comment: Running Python 2.7 on my machine your code worked fine. Can you give a more complete example with the error your experiencing?

Comment: the array has two columns and about 500k rows. I have not done anything extra

Comment: The data structure you posted is a list of list, not a numpy array.   Can you post what is actually printed when you do `print your_array`?  This will help us understand the `dtype` of the array.

Comment: the dtype of array is "object"

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You cannot round numpy arrays that are objects, this can be changed with `astype` as long as your array can be safely converted to floats:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(5).astype(np.object)
>>> a
array([0.5137250555772075, 0.4279757819721647, 0.4177118178603122,
       0.6270676923544128, 0.43733218329094947], dtype=object)

>>> np.around(a,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2384, in around
    return round(decimals, out)
AttributeError: rint

>>> np.around(a.astype(np.double),3)
array([ 0.514,  0.428,  0.418,  0.627,  0.437])
```

You will receive similar errors with string, unicode, void, and char type arrays.

Comment: What the OP should do is add the `dtype=float` argument when they create the array.

Comment: @SethMMorton There is clearly a reason that the array is cast as object instead of float. I would be hesitant to suggesting changing overall dtypes without understanding more of the OP's code.

Comment: I'm not sure there was clearly a reason... it could have been a mistake.  We don't know how the array was created.  If there was a reason, I agree with you.  I was just suggesting this in case the OP didn't know.

Comment: @SethMMorton That is a fair enough point, I may be a bit overcautious when it comes to disclaimers attached to statements on SO.

Comment: this solved my problem. I didnt know about handling numpy objects

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
numbers=[22.2,99.123,1213.1230]
newnumbers=[]
for n in numbers:
    newnumbers.append(round(n))
#for comparison
print numbers
print newnumbers
```

Comment: i have a 2-D array with around 500k rows and I want to round to a specific number of decimal places, not completely round them all

Comment: This was just a suggestion, could you not replace round(n) with numpy.around() ?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.around` should work on a list of lists:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = [[41.743617, -87.626839],
           [41.936943, -87.669838],
           [41.962665, -87.65571899999999]]
>>>
>>> np.around(arr, decimals=2)
array([[ 41.74, -87.63],
       [ 41.94, -87.67],
       [ 41.96, -87.66]])
>>> np.round(arr, decimals=2)
array([[ 41.74, -87.63],
       [ 41.94, -87.67],
       [ 41.96, -87.66]])
```

However, note that it doesn't work on python longs. In fact it gives the same error you reported:

```
>>> np.round(3892438942893489234899848939)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/csaftoiu/work/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2401, in round_
    return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
  File "/Users/csaftoiu/work/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 38, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: rint
```

What seems to be happening is that numpy can't convert some of the numbers in your python list to one of its data types. If it's a long then it's not a problem because it's already rounded, but you'll have to work around it.