# Ball/circle shape tracking in video or live feed with OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, video, shapes

As a task for school our group has to create an application that knows when a goal is scored. This means that a ball shaped object passes a line.

First we are attempting to input a video, get OpenCV to track the ball, and then to output it as a video.

I have put a bunch of other code snippets together that I have found on StackOverflow, but it doesn't work.

I am creating a new post because all the other related threads are either C++ or use colour detection instead of the shape detection that we use. I also can't find a clear answer on outputting the video file when it was turned into a series of images.

Following is the code that I have so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('bal.mp4')


fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        if ret == 0:
            break


        frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
        cimg = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,3,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadi$
        if circles == None:
            print "NoneType"
            break
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles.astype(np.double),3))

        for i in circles[0,:]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

        cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',cimg)
        out.write(cimg)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

We get working images, but the video is unplayable with VLC or any other media player.

This is an image from the program:

[image: Frame in clip]

This issue is turning it into a playable video now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you red this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387608/attributeerror-rint-when-using-numpy-round ?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: I'm talking about your error. This post explains some things about this error.

Comment: I meant that none of us have a good enough understanding of numpy to know what is going on in it. The numpy part is taken from another project.

Comment: Try this: np.around(circles.astype(np.double),3)

I think you should learn and read about your tools before you ask. Copy pasting is not the way to go if you want to learn how to program

Comment: Now I get "AttributeError: `NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'`. I expected that `if ret==True:` would prevent empty objects. At least that is what I found.

Comment: what is the resolution of bal.mp4 is it too 640x480 ?

Comment: I double checked and the resolution is indeed 640x480

Comment: If the only issue is that you can't get a playable video file from "out" VideoWriter object, you can change its initial definition to:
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX'), 20, (640, 480));
This works on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this working in the end, but changing it to mp4 worked for me on my mac

```
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('static/video/outpy.mp4', 0x7634706d, 20, (frame_width, frame_height))
```