# python opencv - HoughCircles error after pixel manipulation

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, hough-transform

```
def detect_circles():
    img = cv2.imread('img.JPG', 0)
    #img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)
    #cim= cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (15, 15), 0)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30,param1=100,param2=39,minRadius=25,maxRadius=70)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    count = 0
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        count = count + 1
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imwrite('circles_detected.JPG', cimg)
    print(count)
```

This function is designed to detect circles in an image.
It works alright but i need to differentiate between colors.
So i wrote this function which sets the G and R value of every pixel to 0.

```
def iterate_image():
    img = read_img('SDC10004.JPG')
    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            #img.itemset((i,j, 0), 100)
            img.itemset((i,j, 1), 0)
            img.itemset((i,j, 2), 0)

    write_img(img,'SDC10004_selfmade_blue.JPG')
```

When i try to detect circles with the blue pixel image i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Documents/workspace/ImageProcessing/Main.py", line 107, in <module>
detect_circles();
File "/home/user/Documents/workspace/ImageProcessing/Main.py", line 94, in detect_circles
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2610, in around
return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: rint
```

Has anyone encoutered this before?

Comment: Did you try to **print circles** after you **cv2.HoughCircles** to see what you get?

Comment: Yes. Before i manipulated the pixels i drawed the circles in the image and it worked

Comment: After manipulating the pixels i get the error message

Comment: From your error **AttributeError: rint** I would try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387608/attributeerror-rint-when-using-numpy-round) solution. So for you it would be **circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles.astype(double)))**. Not that it actually answers why one image is different from the other...

Comment: thanks for the help.
i tried it but now there is a different error:
   circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles.astype(np.double)))
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'**

Comment: So my guess is that **cv2.HoughCircles** is not detecting any circles on you blue image. That's why your variable **circles** is of type **None**.

Comment: Hm okay. There are at least 3 circles that should be detected.
But i heard that HoughCircles is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I believe I found out what is the problem here.

HoughCircles ins't tricky, you just have to be careful with it's parameterization. This method is based on Canny edge detector which in turn thresholds grayscale images.

The [formula](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) which opencv uses to grayscale images is given by:

```
RGB_to_Gray: 0.299.R + 0.587.G + 0.114.B
```

Since you are zeroing two of the three RGB channels, the intensity of grayscale values will decrease. As a result, your threshold avoids any circle detection and **cv2.HoughCircles** returns **None**. Consequently, since you are not testing if **circles** is of type **None**, your script won't progress when you try to perform **np.around(None)**.

Adjusting **param1** on **cv2.HoughCircles** should do the trick.

> param1 – First method-specific parameter. In case of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT
>   , it is the higher threshold of the two passed to the Canny() edge
>   detector (the lower one is twice smaller)

HoughCircles param1 [source](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles).