# How should I solve my problem with "np.around" method?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to detect circles in an image with openCv using this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy 

im = cv2.imread('/home/elessar/bottle .jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 10, param1 = 100, param2 = 100 ,minRadius = 20, maxRadius = 60)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0, :]:
    cv2.circle(im, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (255,0,0), 2)
    cv2.circle(im, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0,255,0), 5)


cv2.imshow('detected_circle', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I'm getting this error :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'

what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387608/attributeerror-rint-when-using-numpy-round) help?

Comment: I've already tried that and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `cv2.HoughCircles` (`circles`) is `None`. You should handle the case where no circle is found.